Is it possible for any Basic Insignificant Solution, to have infeasible values for decision variables?
Am confused on attempting solution algebraically to a LPP of three decision variables.
The problem is given as the opening problem, in the second chapter, of the book titled: Operations Research Problem Solver, by REA.
Doubt #1: There on solving the problem algebraically, for some cases have negative values for the decision variables. Confused, as till now thought that as the feasible region is formed 'first' by all non-negative values of the decision variables; so only slack variables can be negative, in order to yield BIS (Basic Infeasible Solutions).
Doubt #2:
The book does not give any details, as which combination worked; except that have $(x,y,z) = (13,0,8).$
Here, there should be $6C3 = 20$ basic solutions, out of let $x\leq 20$ be the BFS (Basic feasible solutions), and the rest $(20-x)$ would be BIS (Basic Infeasible Solutions).

But, below not got $x=13,$ or a real value between $13-14?$ I.e., the maximization problem would have converted a real value lying between $13-14$ into the integer value of $13.$ 
Similarly, for the case of $y,$ for which should have got an integer value $=0,$ or a real value lying between $0-1.$
Similarly, for $z$ should have got either an integer value of $8,$ or a real value lying between $7-8.$

The problem is stated as: Maximize the units of Steamship (# of units denoted by: $x$), four-mast sailboat (# of units denoted: $y$), & two-mast sailboat (# of units denoted by: $z$), given their profit being $\$6, \$3, \$2$ respectively, per unit of each.
Each of the $3$ items has the below requirement for processing, by painter, cutter, & the assembler, given their time available being $45, 50, \text{& } 60$ hours respectively :
Per unit of $x:$ need cutter $1$ hour, the painter $2$ hours, & the assembler $4$ hours.
Per unit of $y:$ need cutter $3$ hours, the painter $3$ hours, & the assembler $2$ hours.
Per unit of $z:$ need cutter $1$ hour, the painter $3$ hours, & the assembler $1$ hour.


Formulating the problem, get:
Maximize the profit given by: $Z = 6x + 3y + 2z,$ subject to the structural constraints:
$C1: x + 3y + z \leq 45, C2: 2x + 3y + 3z \leq 50, C3: 4x + 2y + z \leq 60.$
And the obvious non-negativity constraints: $C4: x \geq 0, C5: y \geq 0, C6: z \geq 0$
There are $6C3 = 20$ combinations of finding intersection of $3$ constraints, as have $3$ unknowns. Need choose 3 as Non-basic variables, i.e. set $= 0;$ and the rest $3$ as basic variables.
The Basic solutions corresponding to each of the $20$ intersections is given below, using the algebraic approach, i.e. by adding the slack variables, with one corresponding to each of the $3$ structural constraints, i.e. let they be: $u, v, w.$
The new set of constraints are:
$C1: x + 3y + z + u  = 45, C2: 2x + 3y + 3z + v = 50, C3: 4x + 2y + z + w = 60.$
Non-negativity constraints:
$C4: x\geq 0, C5: y\geq0, C6: z\geq 0, C7: u\geq 0, C8: v\geq 0, C9: w\geq 0.$
Now, finding the values of the tuple ($x, y, z, u, v, w$) for each of the $20$ cases, by setting the Non-basic variables $=0:$

$x,y,z$ as Non-Basic variables; & $u,v,w$ as Basic variables: Tuple is> $(0,0,0,45,50,60);$

$x,y,u$ as Non-Basic variables; & $z,v,w$ as Basic variables: Tuple is>$(0,0,45,0,-85,15)$: BIS

$x,y,v$ as Non-Basic variables; & z,u,w as Basic variables: Tuple is> $(0,0,\frac{50}3,\frac{85}3,0,\frac{110}3);$

$x,y,w$ as Non-Basic variables; & $z,u,v$ as Basic variables: $(0,0,60,-15,-130,0):$ BIS

$x,z,u$ as Non-Basic variables; & $y,v,w$ as Basic variables: Tuple is> $(0,15,0,0,5,30);$

$x,z,v$ as Non-Basic variables, & $y,u,w$ as Basic variables: $(0,50/3,0,-5,0,\frac{80}3):$ BIS

$x,z,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $y,u,v$ as Basic variables: $(0,30,0,-45,-40,0):$ BIS

$x,u,v$ as Non-Basic variables, & $y,z,w$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: 3y+z=45, C2: 3y+3z=50 \implies z=\frac52.$


Put $z=\frac52$ in $C1: 3y +\frac52=45 \implies y = \frac{85}6.$ Put $z=\frac52, y=\frac{85}6$ in $C3,$ get: $w = 60 - (\frac52+\frac{85}3) = 60 - \frac{185}6 = \frac{175}6.$
Tuple is> $(0,\frac{85}6,\frac52,0,0,\frac{175}6).$

$x,u,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $y,z,v$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: 3y + z = 45, C3: 2y + z = 60 \implies y=-15.$ BIS.

$x,v,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $y,z,u$ as Basic variables: Take $C2: 3y + 3z = 50, C3: 2y + z = 60 \implies z = -80.$ BIS.

$y,z,u$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,v,w$ as Basic variables: $(45,0,0,0,-40, -120):$ BIS.

$y,z,v$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,u,w$ as Basic variables: $(25,0,0,20,-40):$ BIS.

$y,z,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,u,v$ as Basic variables: Tuple is> $(15,0,0,30,20,0).$

$y,u,v$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,z,w$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: x + z =45, C2: 2x+3z=50 \implies z = -40.$ BIS.

$y,u,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,z,v$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: x + z = 45, C3: 4x + z = 60 \implies x=5.$ Put, $x=5,$ in $C1,$ get: $z=40.$


Put $x=5, z=40,$ in $C2,$ get: $v= -80.$ BIS.

$y,v,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,z,u$ as Basic variables: Take $C2: 2x + 3z = 50, C3: 4x + z = 60 \implies z=8.$ Put $z=8,$ in $C2,$ get: $x=13.$ Put $x=13, z=8,$ in C1, get: $u = 24.$ Tuple is> $(13,0,8,24,0,0).$

$z,u,v$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,y,w$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: x+3y = 45, C2: 2x+3y = 50 \implies x=5.$ Put $x=5,$ in $C1,$ get: $y=\frac{40}3.$ Put $x=5, y=\frac{40}3, \text{ in } C3, \text{ get: } w = 60 - 20 - \frac{80}3 = \frac{40}3.$ Tuple is> $(5,\frac{40}3,0,0,0,\frac{40}3).$

$z,u,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,y,v$ as Basic variables: Take $C1: x + 3y = 45, C3: 4x +2y = 60 \implies x=9.$ Put $x=9, \text{ in } C1,$ get: $y=12.$ Put $x=9, y=12, \text{ in } C2,$ get: $v = -4.$ BIS.

$z,v,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,y,u$ as Basic variables: Take $C2: 2x+3y=50, C3: 4x+2y=60 \implies y=10.$ Put $y=10, \text{ in } C2,$ get: $x=10.$


Put $x=y=10, \text{ in } C1,$ get: $u = 10.$ Tuple is> $(10,10,0,10,0,0).$

$u,v,w$ as Non-Basic variables, & $x,y,z$ as Basic variables: $C1: x+3y+z=45, C2: 2x+3y+3z=50, C3: 4x+2y+z=60.$

Take $C2-C1: x+2z=5 <(a).$ Take $3*C3 - 2*C2: 8x-3z=80 <(b)$
Take $3*(a)+2*(b): 19x = 175  \implies x= 175/19.$
Put, $x=175/19, z = (5-175/19)/2 =$ negative value. BIS.

I'm not 100% sure I follow your questions but if I understand you correctly: (1) basic solutions are infeasible if they don't match the constraints -- there's nothing special about decision variables vs slack variables here; (2) I suspect they didn't include the details of the 20 different solutions because they thought those details were (a) boring, (b) homework, or (c) both, but it would be much as you did -- get the 20 solutions, throw out the infeasible ones, and then check which of the feasible ones is optimal. (I don't know why you claim their solution is bad -- it's #16 on your list.)


Some linear programming problem has nonnnegative constraint, but not all of them, thus, you must be referring to certain form of linear programming problem. For your particular form of linear programming problem, the feasible region is formed by both the nonnegative variable as well as the other constraints as well. Negative slack variable implies that a decision lies on the wrong side of the boundary, hence when this happens, it is infeasible.

For example, consider the following feasible region.
$$\{(x,y): x\ge 0, y\ge 0, x+y \le 1, x-y\le 1\}$$
We can solve the linear system forms by $x=0, x-y=1$, we check that $(1,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ are linearly independent and they intersect at $(0, -1)$, it is basic but not feasible as it violates the sign constraint.

From the algorithm and complexity perspective, one of the main goal of linear programming is not to enumerate every single corner point as the number of corner points can be exponential. Some basic solutions can be overlapping, hence we could have fewer than $20$ basic solutions.

In this case, you have enumerated the solution, and you just have to evaluate the objective value of the feasible ones.
Remark: You could have solved the problem in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not $\mathbb{R}^6$ by setting some inequalities to equality.
