Finding all BFS & BIS points using the slack variables.
Given a LPP, with $m$ structural constraints, and $n$ variables (slack + decision); have usually the formula $nCm$ work out, in finding the number of Basic solution, i.e sum of BIS (Basic Infeasible Solutions + Basic Feasible Solutions).
This was applicable, in my last problem too, as $6C3= 20$ solutions were provided.
But, for the below LPP, given in the Lieberman's book, titled: Introduction to Mathematical Programming, have encountered, for $2$ decision variables, $3$ structural constraints; leading to $\text{n=5, m=3,}$ after $\text{(m=) }3$ slack variables are added to each of the structural constraints.
This has led to my assuming that there would be $5C3 = 10$ Basic solutions, i.e. $10$ intersections among the different structural and non-negativity constraints.
But, there are only $8$ basic solutions (intersections).
How can this deviation be explained?
The problem is stated as below:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\,  Plant & Hours/unit-Product-1 & Hours/unit-Product-2 & Available-Time/Week(Hours) & \\\hline
1    & 1 & 0 & 4\\ \hline
2    & 2 & 0 & 12 \\ \hline
3    & 3 & 2 & 18 \\ \hline
Profit/batch & $3000 & $5000 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
with $Z = 3x_1 + 5x_2, $ with structural constraints: $C1:x_1\leq 4, C2: 2x_2\leq 12, C3: 3x_1 + 2x_2\leq 18.$
The graph of the LPP is attached below, and shows only eight basic solutions.
Kindly help with the doubts in the finding of Basic solutions, as particularly have arisen in cases #$4,5$ below. In both cases, a BIS finding is crucial, as only that particular combination of Basic variables can get it: to point out why the $nCm$ rule has not worked out, in this LPP.

Edit:
If try to see the basic solutions, by adding three slack variables ($x_1, x_2, x_3$), to the three (structural) constraints, then get the new (structural) constraints as:
$C1:x_1 + x_3= 4, C2: 2x_2 + x_4 = 12, C3: 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_5 = 18.$ 
with new non-negativity constraints:
$C4: x_1 \geq 0, C5: x_2 \geq 0, C6: x_3 \geq 0, C7: x_4\geq 0, C8: x_5 \geq 0.$
Now, finding the values of the tuple ($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_3, x_4, x_5$) for each of the $5C2 = 10$ cases, by setting the Non-basic variables $=0:$
1.) $x_1, x_2$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_3, x_4, x_5$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(0,0,4,12,18);$
2.) $x_1, x_3$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_2, x_4, x_5$ as Basic variables: get a system of inconsistent equations as
there are two equations ($2x_2+x_4=12, 2x_2 + x_5 = 18,$) and three unknowns; with obtaining just a relationship between $x_4, x_5;$ as $x_5 = x_4+6.$ The value of $x_2$ is dependent on the value taken by $x_4/x_5$ whichever is taken as a variable.
3.) $x_1, x_4$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_2, x_3, x_5$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(0,6,4,0,6);$
4.) $x_1, x_5$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_2, x_3, x_4$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(0,9,4,-6,0):$ BIS. This BIS can only be obtained using this particular combination of basic variables.
But, there could be taken $x_2=6$ too, and then have tuple: $(0,6,4,0,0).$
5.) $x_2, x_3$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_4, x_5$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(4,0,0,12,6);$
Confused if the value of $x_1$ would be taken as $=4,$ or $=6.$ By $C1, x_1=4;$ but by $C2, x_1=6.$ And, the basic solution (BIS): $(6,0,0,12,0)$ is crucial; as this combination of basic variables alone can get that.
6.) $x_2, x_4$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_3, x_5$ as Basic variables: get a system of inconsistent equations as
there are two equations ($x_1+x_3=12, 3x_1 + x_5 = 18$), and three unknowns; with obtaining just a relationship between $x_3, x_5;$ as $x_5 = x_3+6.$ The value of $x_1$ is dependent on the value taken by $x_3/x_5$ whichever is taken as a variable.
7.) $x_2, x_5$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_3, x_4$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(4,0,0,12,0),$ with $x_3=0$ only;
8.) $x_3, x_4$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_2, x_5$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(4,6,0,0,-6): $ BIS;
9.) $x_3, x_5$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_2, x_4$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(4,3,0,4,0);$
10.) $x_4, x_5$ as Non-Basic variables; & $x_1, x_2, x_3$ as Basic variables: the tuple is> $(2,6,2,0,0);$
Seems the answer lies in the last three solutions, being the same; i.e. $(8), (10).$
But, that way the solutions $(2), (3), (4)$ are also the same.
Also in a similar way, the solutions $(5), (6), (7)$ too are the same.
The basic feasible solutions obtained are all five in the five-sided convex feasible region, given by: $(1), (3), (7), (9), (10).$ 
Also, get the BIS corresponding to: $(x_1=0, x_2=9) \text{ in }(5); (x_1=6, x_2=0)$ in $(4); $ & $(x_1=4, x_2=6) \text{ in }(8).$

How many slack variables added?

@goldboy Seems my edit is correct, and the number of slack variables are: $3,$ i.e.one per (structural) constraint.

Basic variables are not "just take $m$ variables among the $n$ variables!" The chosen set of variables must also lead to the submatrix obtained by selecting the corresponding columns to be invertible. This is to ensure that, by setting the non basic variables to 0, the equation $Ax=b$ has a solution. In your case, there are combinations that does not lead to an invertible matrix.
Also, check your calculations for the case of $(x_1,x_2,x_4)$ being basic variables.

@MarcDinh Thanks for your comment, am able to get one more BFS, i.e. $(4,3,0,4,0).$ Though would request help for the missing one BFS, & one BIS points, as mentioned in the post.

@jiten Honestly, there is not so much help I can provide. Just check that your calculations are correct, for all of your combinations.

@MarcDinh Have got good results following your kind advice, but still issues are there, as stated above too, for cases #$4,5.$

Actually we do not need to bring to problem to $5$ dimension.
We can stay in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and visualize the solution.

If $x_1=0$, the solution is on the $y$-axis.
If $x_2=0$, the solution is on the $x$-axis.
If $x_3=0$, it simply means $x_1=4$, i.e. $C_1$ is active.
If $x_4=0$, it means $x_2=6$, $C_2$ is active.
If $x_5=0$, it means $3x_1+2x_2=18$, $C_3$ is active.


We pick two constraints to be active to solve for the basic solutions. In total, we have at most $\binom{5}{2}$ solutions.

If $x_1=x_2=0$, we get the origin, (0,0).
If $x_1=0$ and $C_1$ is active, the two lines are parallel and do not intersect.
If $x_1=0$ and $C_2$ is active, we obtain $(0,6)$.
If $x_1=0$ and $C_3$ is active, then we have $(0,9)$. This is infeasible. Note that we can't have $(0,6)$, it has to be the $y$-intercept of $3x_1+2x_2=18$.
$x_2=0$ and $C_1$ is active, the point is $(4,0)$.
$x_2=0$ and $C_2$ is active, there is no intersection as they are parallel.
$x_2=0$ and $C_3$ is active, we have $(6,0)$, this is infeasible.
$C_1$ and $C_2$ are active, we have $(4,6)$ this is infeasible.
$C_1$ and $C_3$ are active, we have $(4,3)$.
$C_2$ and $C_3$ are active, we have $(2,6)$.

In summary:

Case $1,3,5,9,10$ corresponds to each of the corners.
Case $4,7,8$ are intersection of two constraints that are outside the feasible region.
Case $2$ and case $6$ involve constraints are linearly dependent and the systems can't be solved as they are inconsistent. These two cases are makes you do not observe $10$ intersections but $10-2=8$ intersections.

Ultimately, simplex algorithm doesn't want you to visit every single corner point.

The check for the infeasible points must need the use of slack variables, as in this problem, none of the two decision variables $x_1, x_2$ are negative, for any of the $3$ BIS.

For case $4$, the point is $(0,9)$, which violates $C_2$, i.e. $x_4<0$. Similar argument for other BIS.

Kindly see my post on related topic at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4964921/424260.

Please tell if relationship exists between #BFS to: $m:$ # of slack variables (structural constraints), $n:$ #decision variables (d.v.). My post at:                  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4960615/424260, with $m=n=3,$ has $8$ bfs. While here, for $n=2, m=3,$ have $5$ bfs, with $2$ inconsistent systems of equations. $C^{m+n}_m =20$ for my earlier post, while $=10$ here. There seems no link, as for a $n$ d.v. problem, can have $m>n.$ Say, here can easily add another constraint, by having another (fourth) plant that processes both products. Even more such constraints can be added here.

From $n$ and $m$ alone, we do not have sufficient information to determine the number of BFS exactly. We have $\binom{m+n}{m}$ as an upperbound.
